# javascript specific alert when textbox is empty in maximum of 3 numbers algorithm

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and trying to solve an algorithm using javascript. I have to find the maximum out of 3 numbers input in 3 textboxes and alert it. I have done that but I still have to alert some messages when textboxes are left empty, without inputs.
So when all 3 fields remain empty I have to generate a specific alert message and although I wrote something, I always get: "NaN" alert. Instead of NaN I want to get: "Introduceti cel putin un numar". Can you help me with this?
Here is my code (html and javascript).

Thanks!

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Algoritmi</title>
    <script src="point2.js">

    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <form name="mainForm" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" name="textBox1" /> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="textBox2" /> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="textBox3" /> <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Afiseaza maxim" onclick=" javascript: calcMax()" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And Javascript:

```
function calcMax() {
    var a = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox1.value);
    var b = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox2.value);
    var c = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox3.value);
    var max;
    if (a == null || a == "" && b == null || b == "" && c == null || c == "") {
        alert("Introduceti cel putin un numar");
    }
    else {
        if (a > b) {
            if (a > c) {
                max = a
            }
            else {
                max = c;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (b > c) {
                max = b
            }
            else {
                max = c;
            }
        }
        alert(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note 1:** `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, you should wrap `||` test in parenthesis.

**Note 2:** You can just check the `length` of tha values to check if they are empty or not.

**Note 3:** To calculate the max of the three value, you can simply use `Math.max`.

```
function calcMax() {
    // no need for parseInt
    var a = document.mainForm.textBox1.value;               // you can add .trim() at the end to remove surrounding spaces
    var b = document.mainForm.textBox2.value;               // ...
    var c = document.mainForm.textBox3.value;               // ...
    var max;

    if (a.length * b.length * c.length === 0) {             // at least one of the inputs value's length is 0
        alert("You must fill the inputs");
    }
    else if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || isNaN(c)) {             // at least one of the inputs value is not a valid number
        alert("inputs must be filled with numbers");
    }
    else {
        max = Math.max(a, b, c);                            // a, b and c are all numbers, use Math.max to calculate the maximum (at this stage a, b and c are string, Math.max will internally convert them to numbers)
        alert(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ibrahim, it works! :) and thanks for the explanations too!

Answer (score 1):

when you convert empty value to int it will be NaN(not a number) so you need to handle this condition using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)(value). isNaN returns true if it's value is not a number other wise false.

After parseInt() step the value of `a` will be NaN if the input value is empty. now i added isNaN(a) condition in your if condition

```js
function calcMax() {
    var a = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox1.value);
    var b = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox2.value);
    var c = parseInt(document.mainForm.textBox3.value);
    var max;
  
    if ((a == null || a == "" || isNaN(a) ) && (b == null || b == ""  || isNaN(b)) && (c == null || c == ""  || isNaN(c))) {
        alert("Introduceti cel putin un numar");
    }
    else {
        if (a > b) {
            if (a > c) {
                max = a
            }
            else {
                max = c;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (b > c) {
                max = b
            }
            else {
                max = c;
            }
        }
        alert(max);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Algoritmi</title>
    <script src="point2.js">

    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <form name="mainForm" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" name="textBox1" /> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="textBox2" /> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="textBox3" /> <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Afiseaza maxim" onclick=" javascript: calcMax()" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```